# how to test the captcha field in javascript?

Tags: javascript, testing, captcha

I was editing the contact page that contains several fields, and finally to add the captcha google,

but the problem that the test fields are made by javascript, but the captcha code that I found on the net is in php,

Of course I want the form to be validated by the captcha, so it must pass only after validation of captcha,

but I have not figured out how to javascript test the captcha, if it is checked or not ??

I tried with this code, it displays but without sending the validation captcha

```
<Script>
if (response.length == 0)
{
alert ('! captcha verified');
document.form.container.focus ();

return false;
}
else if (response.length! = 0)
{
alert ('! captcha not verified');

return true;
}
</ Script>

 <Small> Are you a robot? </ Small>
<Div id = "captcha_container" name = "container"> </ div>
              <Script src = "https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api.js?onload=loadCaptcha&render=explicit" async defer> </ script>
```

So how I test in js?

Thinks.

Comment: i think to do that you need to make a captcha yourself and post it to google via ajax and then check result, since the php version posts to google via curl or socket, so you should manualy do similar in js